# How to align text right when no imageview present?

Tags: android

I have listview with following xml ( list_row.xml )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/settings_list_item"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtItemName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="@string/settings_item_1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSubItemName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/rightArrow"
        android:text="rightItem"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rightArrow"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now this displays `rightItem` before the `>` image. But somtimes I do not want to display the right arrow, in that case if I set its visibility to `gone` then my Textview moves to left side, which actually I want to display on totally right side. How can I accomplish this requirement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#dddd"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtItemName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="#000"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSubItemName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/rightArrow"
        android:text="rightItem"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rightArrow"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You are using **RelativeLayout-specific** attributes in a LinearLayout... ??? See: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_relative_layout.htm

Comment: That will show in lint warning and the rest of the thing depends upon user2060383. user2060383 should use his/her brain to overcome these minor issues.

Comment: ... "minor issues". Couldn't you directly write a correct answer? New users might be confused.

Comment: user having 27 answer 14 question 46 tags and approx 600 score and still not knowing this minor thing. Really amazing. I believe in helping not in spoon feeding boss.

Comment: As for I see it, it's a really **poor quality answer**: AS IS, it **doesn't work**

Comment: it depends on user's view :)

Answer (score 1):

You have tried `GONE`.
Have you tried `INVISIBLE`?

```
.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

---

I see.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSubItemName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/rightArrow"
        android:gravity="right" <!-- ADD THIS -->
        android:text="rightItem"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
```

**So add:** `android:gravity="right"`

Comment: in that case it will simply hide the arrow image, but it doesnt set the text to right align. I want to set text right align when arrow is invisible.

Answer (score 1):

Another answer with relative layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#dddd"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtItemName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="#000"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rightArrow"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSubItemName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/rightArrow"
        android:text="rightItem"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```